# Combine dates from a column into a single cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I combine multiple dates?. For example, dates for whole year 2020 into a single cell in Excel.
Now, I have dates in A column starting from 2020-01-01 till 2020-12-31 and I want to concatenate this dates into a single row in a format '2020-01-01','2020-01-02',....

Comment: Have you got `TEXTJOIN()`?

Comment: Can't you just use the ```Concatenate``` function?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on which column you are using you can use the following:

Type `=Concatenate(A1:A10&",")` then highlight the `A1:A10&","` and press f9 to show the cell contents.

Delete the `{ }` around the new range and press enter.

Change the range to whatever range you have the dates in and this should work.

Comment: I tried this but i don't know how to put A1:A10 in '', for example 'A1','A2',... I solved the problem with TEXTJOIN()